# How to save/read an image to/from the iPhone device storage?

Tags: swift

I am going to save an image into the iphone device and read from it.
So I had written like this for this function.

```
/*
 *  save image to local device
 */
func saveImageToLocal(image: UIImage, fileName: String) {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        let filePath = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        try? data.write(to: filePath, options: .atomic)
    }
}

/*
 *  get image from local device
 */
func getImageFromLocal(fileName:String) -> UIImage? {
    if let filePath = "\(self.getDocumentsDirectory())\(fileName)" as String! {
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            return image
        }
    }
    return nil
}

/*
 *  get document directory to save/read local file
 */
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

But it didn't work correctly.
Which mistake do I have for this?
How can I implement this?
Regards.

Comment: Why is `filePath` created so differently in your save and get methods? Update the get method to create it like you do in your save method.

Comment: Thank you! Your help is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem in getting `filePath` inside your `getImageFromLocal(fileName:) -> UIImage?` method. Change this according to your `saveImageToLocal(image:)` method as like below:

```
func getImageFromLocal(fileName:String) -> UIImage? {
    let filePath = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath.path) {
        return image
    }
    return nil
}
```